# How to use REST using Post Method to get XML information in android?

Tags: android, rest, xml-parsing, httpclient

For example,

```
URI: http://99.99.99.99:8080/services/api/products/getProduct

Method: POST

Content-Type: application/xml
```

Then, I use Advanced Rest Client can get these data

```
<Products>
  <Product>
    <category>Apple</category>
    <productCode>A1</productCode>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <category>Orange</category>
    <productCode>A2</productCode>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <category>Banana</category>
    <productCode>A3</productCode>
  </Product>
....
</Products>
```

How if I want to store all of the category and productCode.

What kinds of method should i use?

HttpPost? XML parser?

This is the sample code I try and I get nothing from the logcat.

```
public void getXml(){    

            String result = "";

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            try {

                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://99.99.99.99:8080/services/api/products/getProduct");

                HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post); 

                HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();

                if (resEntity != null) {    
                    result = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            }

             System.out.println(result);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your issue mainly you are calling the api in main thread,

But you have to call this api in background thread

**Use AsynTask**

```
    public class GetDetails extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    String response = null;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {

    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    int timeoutConnection = 3000;
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
    // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) 
    // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
    int timeoutSocket = 5000;
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
    HttpPost httppost = null;

    httppost = new HttpPost("http://99.99.99.99:8080/services/api/products/getProduct");

    httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
    httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/xml");

    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httppost);

    InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
    if (inputStream != null)
         response = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
    else
        response = null;

    Log.v("data for list", response);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Cann", e.toString());
        }

        return strings[0];
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
           if(response != null){
           XmlPullParserFactory factory =XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
             factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
             XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

             xpp.setInput(new StringReader (result));
             int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
             while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
              if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
                  System.out.println("Start document");
              } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                  System.out.println("End document");
              } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                  System.out.println("Start tag "+xpp.getName());
              } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                  System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());
              } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
             System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());       
              }
              eventType = xpp.next();
             }
         }
      }

private String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream)
        throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        result += line;

    inputStream.close();
    return result;

}   

}
```

And last where you calling the `getXml()` method change to `new GetDetails().execute("")`

Comment: after calling new GetDetails().execute(""), "Cann" log says it is java.io.FileNotFoundException

Comment: yes, i can get data from Advanced Rest Client. maybe is the code problem

Comment: Aman, there is a problem between inputStream and reader, do you have any suggestions to fix this? Thank alot.

Comment: i thing while converting the inputStream into String,exception is coming i added the function can you that

Comment: Aman, thx, you are my hero, it can finally show the data in the logcat, and now i am working on how to separate the data.  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Products>
  <Product>
    <category>Apple</category>
    <productCode>A1</productCode>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <category>Orange</category>
    <productCode>A2</productCode>
  </Product>
  <Product>

Comment: what method should  I use that can easily to store the data? just like {Apple, Orange}, {A1, A2}.

Comment: first you have to parse the data then only  you have  store that data in arraylist, i am adding the code which help you to parsing the data.

Comment: hi, Aman. Do you have interest to discuss my new question, thx alot                (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31779473/how-to-call-web-service-to-achieve-login-system-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the output of `System.out.println` is not visible in logcat.

You should use [Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) class instead:

```
Log.d("test", result);
```

Also you must make sure that your request is [done in a separate thread](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#AsyncTask).

Comment: Network operations must be done in a separate thread: http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#AsyncTask